# OpenNETCF.Stopwatch -> only ticks changing, not Elapsed

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, opennetcf, opennetcf.ioc

I've been trying to track down a bug I thought was thread-related, but I think instead there is an issue with the way I am using OpenNETCF's Stopwatch. I am using [OpenNETCF.IoC](http://ioc.codeplex.com) in my application, but for the sake of simplicity I moved the following code directly into a view:

```
public partial class WorkoutView : SmartPart
{
 ...
 private Stopwatch stopwatch; 
 public WorkoutView()
 {  ...
    stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Reset();
    stopwatch.Start(); 

    WorkoutDisplayTimer = new Timer();
    WorkoutDisplayTimer.Interval = 500;
    WorkoutDisplayTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(WorkoutDisplayTimer_Tick);
    WorkoutDisplayTimer.Enabled = true;
 }
 void WorkoutDisplayTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { ...
   stopwatch.Stop();
   lbl.Text = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks.ToString() + "NOT WORKING: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();
   stopwatch.Start();
  }
  ...
}
```

Long story short, looking at stopwatch in the debugger, the only values that ever get updated are ElapsedTicks, mElapsed, mStartPerfCount. Everything else is always zero. Is this expected behavior? Do I need to call an additional method to have the stopwatch calculate the Elapsed struct? (Note: stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds is also zero)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it appears to be a bug, specifically in Stopwatch.cs, line 136.

It currently reads:

```
smFreqInTicks = (MILLIS_IN_TICKS * 1000) / freq;
```

it should read:

```
smFreqInTicks = (MILLIS_IN_TICKS * 1000d) / freq;
```

Right now smFreqInTicks ends up being always zero, which kills the values you're looking at.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Any chance you're going to make a release with a bugfix sometime soon? I'm currently using the Community SDF so unfortunately I do not have access to the source code to make my own patch.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the version in the Compact Framework itself? It's in [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) from version 3.5 onwards...

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Haven't gotten around to testing the CF.Net version yet, but if there are no problems with it I will switch over.